# Different lint.xml for different build types in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, lint

I want to use different *lint.xml* files for **release** and **debug** build types in Android Studio. So, how can this be achieved?

When I place *lint.xml* in *someModule/src/debug* and *someModule/src/release* folders (also, these folders contain only that *lint.xml* file and nothing more) gradle reacts as there is no any *lint.xml* file, If I place single *lint.xml* file under core module folder (someModule/)- gradle recognizes it, but in this case I can't use different settings depending on build type...

Comment: What if you write a function that dynamically renames the unwanted `lint.xml` files, leaving just the one you want for that flavor?

Comment: I'm open to any kind of solution. including file system manipulation.

Comment: Did you eventually find a solution to this?

Comment: @DataGraham Sorry, no. Try to use Loda's answer.

Answer (score 5):

Here's what worked for me:

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name.startsWith("lint")) {
        if (task.name.toLowerCase().endsWith("release")) {
            task.doFirst {
                android.lintOptions.abortOnError = true
            }
        } else {
            task.doFirst {
                android.lintOptions.abortOnError = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my case I needed to turn on `abortOnError` for release builds so that I can develop freely but catch lint errors quickly on my CI (if they slipped).

Comment: This doesn't specify explicit lint file rather just continues to build in case of lint error.

Answer (score 4):

I did not try it, but maybe something like this could help you.

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'lintDebug') {
        task.ext.lintXmlFileName = "lint-debug.xml"
    } else if (task.name == 'lintDemo') {
        task.ext.lintXmlFileName = "lint-demo.xml"
    }
}
```

EDIT: comments feedback:

- task.ext.xxxx is a custom name space for you to use: see https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html
- "lintXmlFileName" is a made up name. You won't find doc about it.
- in android{... lintOptions {... lintConfig file("lint.xml")}} you need to read "lintXmlFileName" using ".ext.get("lintXmlFileName")" and set it for "lintConfig file()"
- I did not test it, but I assume the "whenTaskAdded" goes outside of "android" in your app's build.gradle.

Comment: I tried this solution, but I wasn't able to get it to work.  Where should this script go within the build.gradle file?  At the top-level or within "android"?  Is this all there is to it, or do you need to put something special under android{lintOptions{}} as well?  I can't find any documentation for the "lintXmlFileName" property.

Answer (score 1):

With kotlin build scripts (`build.gradle.kts`):

```
tasks.withType<LintBaseTask>().configureEach {
    // doFirst is required else we get a Null Pointer Exception on lintOption
    doFirst {
        // This will override the lintOptions from the android extension
        lintOptions.run {
            if (name.toLowerCase().contains("debug")) {
                // Do your configuration here
                // isAbortOnError = true
                // baselineFile = file("baseline.xml")
                // isWarningsAsErrors = true
                // isCheckDependencies = true
                // ignore("MissingTranslation")
                // setLintConfig(file("lint.xml"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is summary from Android studio new build system guide, [lint support](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Lint-support).

**Lint support**

*As of version 0.7.0, you can run lint for **a specific variant, or for all variants**, in which case it produces a report which describes which specific variants a given issue applies to.*

*You can configure lint by adding a lintOptions section like following. You typically only specify a few of these; this section shows all the available options.*

```
android {

    lintOptions {

        // set to true to turn off analysis progress reporting by lint
        quiet true
        // if true, stop the gradle build if errors are found
        abortOnError false
        // if true, only report errors
        ignoreWarnings true
        // if true, emit full/absolute paths to files with errors (true by default)
        //absolutePaths true
        // if true, check all issues, including those that are off by default
        checkAllWarnings true
        // if true, treat all warnings as errors
        warningsAsErrors true
        // turn off checking the given issue id's
        disable 'TypographyFractions','TypographyQuotes'
        // turn on the given issue id's
        enable 'RtlHardcoded','RtlCompat', 'RtlEnabled'
        // check *only* the given issue id's
        check 'NewApi', 'InlinedApi'
        // if true, don't include source code lines in the error output
        noLines true
        // if true, show all locations for an error, do not truncate lists, etc.
        showAll true
        // Fallback lint configuration (default severities, etc.)
        lintConfig file("default-lint.xml")
        // if true, generate a text report of issues (false by default)
        textReport true
        // location to write the output; can be a file or 'stdout'
        textOutput 'stdout'
        // if true, generate an XML report for use by for example Jenkins
        xmlReport false
        // file to write report to (if not specified, defaults to lint-results.xml)
        xmlOutput file("lint-report.xml")
        // if true, generate an HTML report (with issue explanations, sourcecode, etc)
        htmlReport true
        // optional path to report (default will be lint-results.html in the builddir)
        htmlOutput file("lint-report.html")

       // set to true to have all release builds run lint on issues with severity=fatal

       // and abort the build (controlled by abortOnError above) if fatal issues are found

       checkReleaseBuilds true

        // Set the severity of the given issues to fatal (which means they will be
        // checked during release builds (even if the lint target is not included)
        fatal 'NewApi', 'InlineApi'
        // Set the severity of the given issues to error
        error 'Wakelock', 'TextViewEdits'
        // Set the severity of the given issues to warning
        warning 'ResourceAsColor'
        // Set the severity of the given issues to ignore (same as disabling the check)
        ignore 'TypographyQuotes'
    }

}
```

**EDIT: add the real and workable example**

As we all know, the new Android build system is based on gradle. The core component of the gradle build system is `task`. There are different lint tasks if you project has different build variant. You can get those tasks from android studio `All task list`, or from commandline `./gradlew tasks`. A example show as following, two build flavors `demo` and `full`.

```
lint - Runs lint on all variants.
lintDemoDebug - Runs lint on the DemoDebug build
lintDemoRelease - Runs lint on the DemoRelease build
lintFullDebug - Runs lint on the FullDebug build
lintFullRelease - Runs lint on the FullRelease build
```

These lint task are dependency on other tasks, here let's say `preBuild`.

Before run the lint task, it will run the task `preBuild` firstly. The task `preBuild` is an already existing task, but we can manipulate this pre-defined task and add more action to this task. android `lintOptions` property will be added and modified dynamically based on different build variants as the following code demonstrate in the file `app/build.gradle`.

```
preBuild.doFirst {
android.applicationVariants.each { variant ->
    if (variant.name == 'demoDebug') {
        println variant.name
        android.lintOptions.quiet = true
        android.lintOptions.lintConfig = new File('app/lint_demo_debug.xml')
        // you can add more properties
    } else if (variant.name == 'fullDebug') {
        println variant.name
        android.lintOptions.quiet = false
        android.lintOptions.lintConfig = new File('app/lint_full_debug.xml')
        // you can add more properties
    } // more variants...
}
```

In order to run the code above successfully, the corresponding lint configuration file must exist under app directory.

Comment: Thanks, I saw this documentation. But How does this help us to have different lint.xml file per buildType ?

Comment: I don't think this works.  It iterates over all variants, and each time it sets a global configuration, so whichever variant comes last, those options will be set globally.

Comment: You're right, this will just keep the last variant's value, see my answer for how I did this.