# Different lint-options per build type

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, lint

I want to have different lint options per build-type.
I tried to simply add the options to the corresponding build types like this:

```
android {    
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            lintOptions {
                textReport true
                textOutput 'stdout'
                warningsAsErrors false
                abortOnError true
            }
        }
        release {
            lintOptions {
                textReport true
                textOutput 'stdout'
                ignoreWarnings false
                warningsAsErrors true
                abortOnError true
            }
        }
    }
```

but this does not work as expected:
e.g. in my project I have some lint warnings, but no errors. Thus I'd expect

```
./gradlew lintRelease
```

to fail, but

```
./gradlew lintDebug
```

to succeed (with warnings of course).
But this is not the case. With the config shown above, both builds fail.

The strange thing is, that it is dependent on the order: e.g. when I move the whole `debug {}` block after `release {}`, then both builds always succeed: so it seems that only the latest options are ever used...

What am I missing - or how to fix this?

I use gradle version 3.3

Comment: According to the [DSL](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/) there is only one global lintOptions (and not one per build-type). This explains why the latest config always wins in my example...

Answer (score 0):

as a workaround we can use a gradle property which we can set to "debug"/"release": as explained here: [Gradle plugin does not propagate debug/release to dependencies - Comment#91](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=52962#c91)

e.g. in the `gradle.properties` file of the project define a variable:

```
myBuildType=debug
```

This will make sure that the default build type is "debug". You can override it via a gradle command line argument

```
./gradlew.bat -PmyBuildType=release ...
```

and in the build.gradle file of the project or subprojects:

```
warningsAsErrors rootProject.properties['myBuildType'] == 'release'
```

Answer (score 0):

[This answer may be helpful to you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23382196/different-lint-xml-for-different-build-types-in-android-studio)

I solved the problem in a different way.

Add this task in your app build.gradle after the android { } block.

```
task setReleaseLintOptions {
    doLast {
        configure(android.lintOptions) {
            // Put your specific lintOptions here
            check 'ExtraTranslation', 'MissingTranslation', 'Untranslatable'
        }
    }
}

task setDebugLintOptions {
    doLast {
        configure(android.lintOptions) {
            // Put your specific lintOptions here
            check 'MissingDefaultResource', 'UnusedResources'
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can manually run these tasks before your lint tasks to configure the lint options before that run...

`.gradlew setReleaseLintOptions lintRelease`

`.gradlew setDebugLintOptions lintDebug`

This would run the options specified in our custom tasks for the lintRelease or lintDebug task.